# Matlab textscan formatspec delimiter error

Tags: matlab, csv, delimiter, large-files, textscan

When reading a large csv file Matlab doesn't recognize ||,|| as a proper delimiter as input argument for textscan. The data is as follows (simplified):

```
||X||,||Y||,||Z|| (header)
||1||,||2||,||4||
||4||,||4||,||3||
```

etc.

I use `data = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,'Delimiter',',');` to read in the data with some format spec `'%f %f %f'`.

My rubber band solution has been to use 010 editor to replace all '||' with '', making it a proper csv file for matlab, but due to the size of the document (6M lines with approx 35 fields) and the frequency of new documents this is hardly a great solution.

Does anyone know a proper way to import such a file?

Comment: I'd say find a way to create your files as a COMMA separated file, not a pie pie comma pipe pipe-separated file. That being said, you can probably get the two pipes as a string and separate them out that way, i.e. `%s %f %s` as format spec.

Comment: The creation of the file is not up to me, so I can't make it a true comma separated file.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to include it in the format specifier:

```
data = textscan(fid, '||%f||,||%f||,||%f||', 'headerlines', 1)
```

and then just leave out the delimiter.

**Edit** (Following on from comments)

If you are trying to read in strings, the trick is to get it to read in strings without the `|` character. This is done using `%[^|]`, like this:

```
data = textscan(fid, '|| %[^|] ||,|| %[^|] ||,|| %[^|] ||', 'headerlines', 1)
```

Comment: doesnt it place all numbers in 1 cell now? i.e. `textscan(fid,'||%f||', 'delimiter', ',')`

Comment: Well, yes, if you do `textscan(fid,'||%f||', 'delimiter', ',')` you get it all in one cell. But using what I did I get the results in three cells - just checked it.

Comment: Ah, I do you mean he might want them all in one cell?

Comment: No, for sure not. I thought your solution did that, since you did not specify the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It works perfectly with numbers, but when it tries to read a string it goes wrong. The two entries  `||CFF1368176799564369A951||,||2013-05-02||`  get read as `CFF1368176799564369A951||,||2013-05-02`. After this textscan stops reading. Any suggestions? I've tried messing with %[^|] in the format spec without succes.

Comment: If you use `%s` instead of `%f` you can read in a string. But this would then read in all your numbers as strings too. If it's unclear what the datatype is before you start I would say read in the data as a string and convert it to a number/date/whatever subsequently.

Comment: When trying to read all data as strings a similar error occurs. When specifying ||%s||, Matlab recognizes the fist two '|', but can't find the end and never delimits. So `||aabb||,||bbcc||` reads as `aabb,||,||bbcc||` into a single field, instead of the desired `aabb` `bbcc` in two fields. Is there a way to give the || higher priority as delimiter in the reading of the String that you know of? Thanks anyway for all the suggestions!

Comment: Reading everything as a string and using `strrep` to remove the ||'s fixed it. Still seems more complex than should be needed, but thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Edited to show how you can read in strings avoiding particular characters